# Clear the history of recent commands in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

How to clear the history of recent commands in terminal so that I am unable to scroll through them with *up* and *down* arrow keys? Closing and reopening the terminal doesn't seem to clear the history. Nor does the `reset` command

Answer (score 5):

In case of `bash` you could simply delete the content of `~/.bash_history`.

The following should do it:

```
> ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: This only clears old history, commands from previous sessions. It doesn't clear "recent" history - commands that have been entered this session.

Comment: The history -c command clears the current history, but any new bash session will have the old history.  Removing the bash_history file was a much better solution.